# How to access individual elements of a nalgebra matrix in Rust?

Tags: rust, linear-algebra

I am trying to access the individual elements of an nalgebra matrix in Rust, but keep getting an error. I have not found any examples in the documentation that show how to access individual elements either — as I would with some multidimensional array.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
use nalgebra::DMatrix; // 0.21.0

fn main() {
    let b = DMatrix::<f64>::zeros(4, 4);
    println!("{:?}", b[0][1]);
}
```

When I compile this code, I get

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `f64`
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     println!("{:?}", b[0][1]);
  |                      ^^^^^^^
```

I am not sure how to interpret this message, or where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [the documentation for `Matrix::index`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.21.0/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.index):

```
pub fn index<'a, I>(&'a self, index: I) -> I::Output
where
    I: MatrixIndex<'a, N, R, C, S>,
```

If we look at the [implementers of `MatrixIndex`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.21.0/nalgebra/base/indexing/trait.MatrixIndex.html), we see many types, including a *tuple* of `usize` (`(usize, usize)`):

```
println!("{:?}", b[(0, 1)]);
```

[*The Rust Programming Language* chapter on data types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type) further explains tuples.